# Positioning of Datalabels in a chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying positioning labels of two series in a combo chart. I first position all the series using xlLabelPositionAbove and xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd and then I modify each label, point by point. I'm running the code pressing a button from the sheet "Commenti".The problem is that if I break the code and I select the sheet "Riepilogo" before the For loop, the routine make the first positioning (xlLabelPositionAbove  and xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd). When I run the code without the break and I don't select the sheet "Riepilogo" first, the code doesn't produce the first positioning (xlLabelPositionAbove and xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd). it seems  xlLabelPositionAbove and xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd do produce effects only if the sheet is selected. How can I resolve this issue?
I attach Graph 1 that shows how should be and Chart 2 how it is

```
        With Sheets("Riepilogo").ChartObjects("Chart 4").chart
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = pValue
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "Modello"
            .SeriesCollection.Item(2).XValues = bValue
            .SeriesCollection.Item(2).Values = chrtY
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Benchmark"
            .SeriesCollection.Item(1).XValues = dValue
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = cMin - 0.1 * cMax
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = cMax + 0.1 * cMax
            .SeriesCollection.Item(2).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionOutsideEnd
            Dim k As Integer
            k = 0
            For Each pnt In .SeriesCollection.Item(2).Points
                k = k + 1
                pnt.DataLabel.Top = pnt.DataLabel.Top + 5
                pnt.DataLabel.Left = pnt.DataLabel.Left - 14
                Dim mrg As Double
                mrg = (.SeriesCollection(1).Points(k).DataLabel.Left - pnt.DataLabel.Left)
                If mrg > 0 Then
                    If mrg < 26 Then
                        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(k).DataLabel.Left = pnt.DataLabel.Left
                        .SeriesCollection(1).Points(k).DataLabel.Top = pnt.DataLabel.Top + 14
                    End If
                Else
                ...
                End If
            Next
        End With
exit_sub:
    If rs_Open = True Then: rs_Open = False: Set rs = Nothing
    Erase dValue
    Erase pValue
    Erase bValue
    bMax = 0
    bMin = 0
    pMax = 0
    pMin = 0
    cMax = 0
    cMin = 0

    Application.Cursor = xlDefault
    Application.Worksheets("Commenti").FactsheetOutput.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    avoidEvent = False
Exit Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe try adding a `DoEvents` before the `For` loop  Might be worth editing your code to include the `With` block referenced in the `For Each` loop.  And use a variable to reference the chart and/or series - no need to keep repeating that `Sheets("Riepilogo").ChartObjects("Chart 4").chart.SeriesCollection(1)`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried with DoEvents before For loop, but I still have the same problem